# why my custom error type causes error with specific pattern?

Tags: pointers, go, error-handling

I'm struggling with go's receivers and pointers.
I found that 4th pattern causes error.
Why this pattern causes error and what's the difference?
Thanks in advance.

```
type MyError struct{}

// OK pattern
func (e MyError) Error() string {
    return "something bad happened"
}

func run() error {
    return MyError{}
}

// OK pattern
func (e MyError) Error() string {
    return "something bad happened"
}

func run() error {
    return &MyError{}
}

// OK pattern
func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return "something bad happened"
}

func run() error {
    return &MyError{}
}

// BAD pattern
func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return "something bad happened"
}

func run() error {
    return MyError{}
}
```

Comment: That's because non-pointer types do not include methods of pointer types in their method set: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Answer (score 0):

Go will automatically dereference a pointer for you (pattern 2), however it won't automatically reference one for you. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values for more information.

Comment: It will automatically reference one for you, if it can, but only for a method call, not for the purpose of satisfying an interface.